# Samba share can only be accessed with smbclient but not Explorer from Windows 10?

Tags: samba, samba4

I've set up a Samba server on Linux (Ubuntu 17.04) to share files with my Windows computer.

The server is up and running, but what's strange is that I can only access the shared folder using the `smbclient` command from my Windows Subsystem for Linux environment:

```
smbclient //xxx.xxx.xx.xx/share
```

However, when I use the Windows command line tools for Samba (which is the same as adding a drive map from Explorer):

```
net use \\xxx.xxx.xx.xx\share Z:
```

After putting the same username/password as with the `smbclient`, I get an error message:

```
System error 5 has occurred.  
Access is denied.
```

Nearly everything from my `smb.conf` is by default, and the only configurations I added were:

```
hosts allow = xxx.xx.xx.xx/24 127.0.0.1
```

and

```
[share]  
path = /my/share/folder  
valid users = my_user  
read only = no  
writable = yes  
browsable = yes  
guest ok = no
```

(I also have used `smbpasswd` to set up the username and enabled samba in ufw )

Comment: Please can you provide all the non-comment lines from your smb.conf. (Different distributions seem to provide a different default file.)

Comment: in `smb.conf` under the `[global]` section try adding `max protocol = SMB2`

Comment: win10 disables SMB1 protocol by default, and your linux samba might be defaulting to SMB1.

Comment: What do the (relevant) log files under `/var/log/samba` say?

Comment: - I think you mean 'min protocol = SMB2'. I already tried it didn't work.
- Log doesn't say anything rather than 'Denied access from IP xxx.xxx.xx.xx'. Strange thing is that even for the smbclient access which did come thru it reports the same thing.

Comment: Had the same problem, and setting 'min protocol = SMB2' solved it for me.